# Select Menu On A Wordpress Page

Tags: menus

-1

I'm looking to add a "SELECT MENU" on a Wordpress page, where all 50 states are listed and when the user chooses a state, it would take them to the corresponding state page, like this: http://allightingltd.com/find-a-rep.php .

In a perfect world, the page would be in a frame, where only the state frame would change. Hope this makes sense...

Here's what I came up with and it doesnt work: http://bnrgraphics.com/allightingltd/a-and-l-lighting-find-a-rep/

Comment: You've built a form with two dropdowns - you probably only want one. You also need to set up a form handler. Usually for this type of functionality, you would create a child theme, and in that theme you can set up a page template that checks to see if a state has been submitted. If it has, display that state; if not, display the "find a rep" content and the form to let them choose the state.

Comment: The example you linked to just changes the title of a heading, with the same details for every single state, Also this is really poor UX, and probably not legal under many countries/states accessibility guidelines. Just because that's how it's currently done doesn't mean it's a good idea